# Syntax for putting a block on a single line

Tags: ruby, syntax

So I've got a Ruby method like this:

```
def something(variable, &block)
  ....
end
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
something 'hello' { do_it }
```

Except that isn't working for me, I'm getting a syntax error. If I do this instead, it works:

```
something 'hello' do
  do_it
end
```

Except there I'm kind of missing the nice look of it being on one line.

I can see why this is happening, as it could look like it's a hash being passed as a second variable, but without a comma in between the variables...but I assume that there must be a way to deal with this that I'm missing. Is there?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to parenthesize your argument:

```
something('hello') { do_it }
```

That should work.

Comment: yep, that does it!! Thanks. Sometimes it's the most obvious things you miss ;-)

Comment: @Cameron Booth: So maybe you can Accept his answer?  :)

Comment: If you don't have any parameters I imagine you still need to put the explicit parenthesis otherwise it will pass the block as a parameter instead? ie: `something() { do_it }`

Comment: Any idea when this changed?  `something 'hello' { do_it }` worked fine in Ruby 2.3.7 - it's everywhere in our controller before_actions

Answer (score 2):

If you want "def something" to to accept a block, you need to yield data to that block. For example:

```
#to uppercase string
def something(my_input)
 yield my_input.upcase
end

# => "HELLO WORLD"
something("hello world") { |i| puts i}
```

Comment: That's not necessarily true. You could yield nothing, pass the block to another method, or choose to ignore it. There's not a specific need to yield anything to the block.

The way the method in the original question was written, the block passwd will be converted to a `Proc` named `block`.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, what about:

```
>> def something(arg1 , &block)
>>   yield block
>> end
=> nil
>> def do_it
>>   puts "Doing it!"
>> end
=> nil
>> something('hello') { do_it }
"Doing it!"
=> nil
```